# jQuery Scroll Path

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

Im trying to work with the jQuery Scrolpath Plugin only im having some issues as there isnt really any guidelines to how it works.

The demo site is http://joelb.me/scrollpath/

If you look in the demo.js you see the following...

```
$.fn.scrollPath("getPath")
    // Move to 'start' element
    .moveTo(400, 50, {name: "start"})
    // Line to 'description' element
    .lineTo(400, 800, {name: "description"})
```

Im wanting to know how does "400,50" place the initial div in the center of my browser? Ive tried playing with these variables only I get really random outputs, has anybody worked with this plugin before?

Answer (score 3):

There is also some documentation on GitHub: https://github.com/JoelBesada/scrollpath

There it states that the `.moveTo()` function essentially moves the centre of the screen to the specified co-ordinate.

So I think rather than thinking of it as the elements in the document being centred in the view of the browser, think of it as the view of the browser being centred onto the elements in the document - i.e. the position of the elements in the document remain unchanged.